# Laravel - Export Excel with filtered date range

Tags: php, laravel

I'll be doing a reports file with a date range. However I'm stuck on where I'll put the array of test entries to the Excel::create() statement. What I tested was tried putting $posts as a compact() however it doesn't work.

Here's my function on it:

```
public function exportDatedPosts(Request $request)
{
        $dateStart = $request->startDate;
        $dateEnd = $request->endDate;
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])->get();

        Excel::create('PostsReport', function($excel) 
        {
            $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) 
            {
                $sheet->loadView('ExImports.DatedPost');
            });
        })->export('csv');
}
```

Comment: are you want to download data in csv ? or excel ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry in csv. just need to filter out the creation dates before downloading/exporting the file

Comment: did you get data in $posts variable ? , and you are able to download the csv file ?

Comment: please tell the exact problem ...

Comment: @SaurabhMistry yes, I got the data in $posts. no I'm unable to download the csv file. I have no idea where to put the $posts contents into the loadView

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the issue. I just need to pass $posts via use($posts) and adding ->with(compact('posts')) into the loadView

```
public function exportDatedPosts(Request $request)
{
    $dateStart = $request->startDate;
    $dateEnd = $request->endDate;
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
            ->distinct()
            ->leftJoin('post_tag', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_tag.post_id')
            ->leftJoin('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'post_tag.tag_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->select('posts.title', 'posts.body' ,'users.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('posts.created_at', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])
            ->get();
    Excel::create('PostsReport', function($excel) use($posts)
    {
        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) use($posts)
        {
           $sheet->loadView('ExImports.DatedPost')->with(compact('posts'));
        });
    })->export('csv');
}
```